# MySQL timestamp format and datediff

Tags: mysql, datediff

Hi I'm writing queries for MySQL, and now my database has a column containing the timestamp in this format: **7/14/2015  7:57:49 AM**, but I need to use the DATEDIFF function, so how can I convert the timestamp into the format like: **2015-7-14** (or 2015-07-14, I'm not sure which one is correct; just the date)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should convert your string to just the date in a date format, then you can use `DATEDIFF` on the date fields in question:

```
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(t,LOCATE(' ',t) - 1), '%m/%d/%Y') FROM my_table;
```

The `LEFT` function will take the substring to the left of the space, which is just your date, then `STR_TO_DATE` will convert that substring to a date the system can use.

(Not knowing your field and table names, I used `t` and `my_table`.)

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. The way MySQL *displays* timestamps has nothing to do with the way they're stored internally; as long as it's `TYPE TIMESTAMP` or some compatible type, the `DATEDIFF()` function will know what to do with it.

TIMESTAMPs are actually stored as a really huge integer representing (I think) milliseconds from Midnight UTC, January 1st, 1970. The display format is determined by a system global variable, and has nothing to do with the actual value.

Converting from a string to a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` is actually also fairly straightforward using the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function; in your case the [format string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) would be something like

```
STR_TO_DATE('%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p', datecol)
```

although you might have to experiment a bit to make it work reliably.

Comment: Currently the column is of type text, and I tried to import the data by declaring that column as type DATETIME, but it's not recognized. I didn't find type TIMESTAMP in the data import wizard. I'm using MySQL workbench.

Comment: Okay, that makes a difference. I'll have an answer for you in a couple of minutes.